# How can I select time twice and display in two different TextViews?

Tags: android, timepicker, clickable

I am developing an app in which i have to select favorable time (from - to timme) by clicking on the image button and display it in TextView.
But my app force closes when i click the image button. Here is the code is used.

**Layout:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmkcg.jpg

**Code:**

```
public class AddClassExperiment extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText a_course_code, a_subject;
TextView a_from_time, a_to_time;
Spinner a_shift_spinner, a_room_spinner, day_selector;
ImageButton a_from_tym_image, a_to_tym_image;
Button save_d_day, delete_d_day;

private Integer hr, min;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID2 = 2;
int cur = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_class);

    a_course_code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year_edittext);
    a_subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subj_edittext);
    a_shift_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shift_spinner);
    a_room_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.room_spinner);
    a_from_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromtym_textView);
    a_to_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totym_textView);
    day_selector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.day_spinner);
    save_d_day = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    delete_d_day = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
    a_from_tym_image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fromtym_image);
    a_to_tym_image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.totym_image);


    a_from_tym_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    a_to_tym_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID2);
        }
    });
}
@Override
@Deprecated
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            cur = TIME_DIALOG_ID;
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hr, min, false);

        case TIME_DIALOG_ID2:
            cur = TIME_DIALOG_ID2;
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hr, min, false);
    }
    return null;
}
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        hr = hourOfDay;
        min = minute;
        String am_pm;
        if (hourOfDay > 12) {
            hr = hourOfDay - 12;
            am_pm = "PM";
        } else {
            hr = hourOfDay;
            am_pm = "AM";
        }
        if (cur == TIME_DIALOG_ID) {
            a_from_time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hr).append(":").append(min).append(am_pm));
        }
        else {
            a_to_time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hr).append(":").append(min).append(am_pm));
        }
        }
    };

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {showDialog(0);}}
```

I may have used unnecessary code, but it was working fine when i used the code without using TIME_DIALOG_ID,but time from both image buttons were displayed in same textView.
Kindly help me with the issue and suggest me a simple method.

Comment: What does your log say? Hard to tell without knowing the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

OK Nice but try This code

//////////////////////
public class Timepicker extends Activity  {

```
TextView mDate, mTime, mTime1, mTime2;


int pHour, pMinute;
int pHour1, pMinute1;
int pHour2, pMinute2;



static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                pHour = hourOfDay;
                pMinute = minute;
                displayToast();
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };

private void updateDisplay() {
    mTime.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(pMinute)));
}

private void displayToast() {
    Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ")
            .append(mTime.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID1 = 1;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener1 =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view1, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                pHour1 = hourOfDay;
                pMinute1 = minute;
                displayToast1();
                updateDisplay1();
            }
        };

private void updateDisplay1() {
    mTime1.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad1(pHour1)).append(":")
                    .append(pad1(pMinute1)));
}

private void displayToast1() {
    Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ")
            .append(mTime1.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private static String pad1(int c1) {
    if (c1 >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c1);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c1);
}

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID2 = 2;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener2 =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view2, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                pHour2 = hourOfDay;
                pMinute2 = minute;
                displayToast2();
                updateDisplay2();
            }
        };

private void updateDisplay2() {
    mTime2.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad2(pHour2)).append(":")
                    .append(pad2(pMinute2)));
}

private void displayToast2() {
    Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ")
            .append(mTime2.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private static String pad2(int c2) {
    if (c2 >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c2);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c2);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timepicker);

    mTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickATime);
    mTime1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickATime1);
    mTime2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickATime2);
    mTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    mTime1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID1);
        }
    });
    mTime2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID2);
        }
    });


    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    pHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    pMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    if (id == TIME_DIALOG_ID) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);

    } else if (id == TIME_DIALOG_ID1) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener1, pHour1, pMinute1, false);

    } else if (id == TIME_DIALOG_ID2) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener2, pHour2, pMinute2, false);

    }


    return null;

}
```

}